# Microsoft Grap wl.signin scope

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to authorize my application using Microsoft Graph. Is there any way to use scope `wl.signin` or something which works the same way?

Every time when I send a request with this scope, I get:

> AADSTS70011: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope wl.signin is not valid.

The `wl.signin` is in "core scopes" such as `wl.basic` or `wl.offline_access`.

In the documentation they are saying the scope such as `wl.offline_access` can be used in the authorization request, but even this returns

> The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid.The scope wl.offline_access is not valid.

Comment: Find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The `wl.` scopes are for the legacy Windows Live authentication model. This is not supported by Microsoft Graph.

You need to use the new [v2 Endpoint](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user) (also known as Converged Auth) and request the [scopes supported by Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference).

I wrote an article (really a series of them) that should help get you started: [Microsoft v2 Endpoint Primer](http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-primer).

Comment: I'll read it, but tell me please, is there option to sign in application for good, so browser won't promt to login any more?

Comment: You can use a `refresh_token` (covered in the article) to keep them authenticated. As long as that `refresh_token` isn't invalidated or otherwise revoked by the tenant then they won't have to login again.